# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.libraries.places:1.0.0:

Tags: android, google-places

I want to use **Google places API**  but I can't sync the project with `"com.google.android.libraries.places:1.0.0:"` dependency. How to add the **places** in my project?.

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`

Comment: Please post your build.gradle. and don't use 'android-studio' tag unless your problem related to Android Studio.

Comment: you should find a good tutorial on internet

Comment: can you suggest a tutorial for me. I try many tutorails, but i didnt clear my doubts. still i dont know how to add nearby places in the google Map.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The library in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start) is wrong I guess, use this, it works.
I had same issue few days back , gave a feedback to them on documentation they still didn't fix it.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0'
```

You can see how to add places autocomplete over [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete)

**Edit:** Seems like they finally fixed the documentation

Comment: I'm trying with the same but i'm still getting could not resolve error :( do i need to change anything else?

Comment: Try adding `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` in project level `build.gradle` below jcentre()

Comment: added it already but it is still giving the same error, it says   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: can you add your build.gradle file , both project and app one

Comment: please help me to list places in to recycleview ?

Comment: Its easier to use their default intent launcher/ fragment instead of populating on recyclerview , Try implementing first using [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete) If you are having any problem then I will help

Comment: com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Places must be initialized.

Comment: Actually i need for list near atm or hotels with user specified coverage. can you help me with that ?

Comment: add this line  `Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "GOOGLE_API_KEY")`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you.

Comment: That helped, thanks! Current version of places library is 2.5

Answer (score 1):

try to change

```
compileOnly "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
```

by

```
api "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also stuck with the same issue, now i removed this issue. According to google,
"The v1.0.0 release of the Places SDK for Android introduces an all-new static library with updated functionality. The Google Play Services version of the Places SDK for Android (in Google Play Services 16.0.0) is deprecated as of January 29, 2019, and will be turned off on July 29, 2019."

Add following dependency it will work...

implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'

For more information you can visit,
https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration